# Find the projection of the given vector b in R^m onto the given hyperplane V subspace of R^m

Tags: linear-algebra

By first finding the projection onto $V$ orthogonal complement, find the projection of the given vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ onto the given hyperplane $V$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I have $V = \{x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $b=(2,1,1)$

I know that since $V$ is a hyperplane it has a normal vector $a = (1,1,1)$ that forms a basis for $V$ ortogonal complement. I dont know how to use this to find $b$ projected onto $V$ ortogonal compliment.
When i know this i can find proj$Vb$, but unsure how to do that too

Comment: Is my edit correct? and is your $\mathbb{R}^m=\mathbb{R}^3$?